# In a boost::multi_array, which is the type of a sub-array?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, boost-multi-array

If I have a

```
boost::multi_array<int,2> myArray(boost::extents[10][10]);
```

Which type is the following?

```
myArray[4]
```

How should I define a reference to it in a function interface?

```
int doSomething(xxxxxx& mySubArray, const int dim) {
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
         std::cout << mySubArray[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating a 10x10 2D array, then trying to index it with '4' - shouldn't the index (`myArray[index]`) be a boost::indices with two values?

Comment: @DavidDoria The point of this question was understanding what type is the *subarray* that you get when using only the first indexing level. For example, because you want to pass a sub array to a function.

Comment: I see, so the `operator[]` gives you the "internal representation" (an array of arrays (of arrays...)) if you give it a single integer, or a subgrid if you give it a `boost::indices`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html#multi_array_class): `boost::multi_array<int, 2>::reference`.

For `NumDims == 2`, this is the type `boost::multi_array<int, 2>::template subarray<1>::type`, or alternately `boost::array_view_gen<boost::multi_array<int, 2>, 1>::type`.  Once the dimensionality of the array view reaches 0, you get an element reference (i.e. `int &`) instead.

Comment: Is it good also for the example function that I have added now? What if there were three levels?

Comment: @Antonio yes, this is generic code.  If `NumDims == 3` then your code would try to stream out a `subarray<1>`, and would probably fail.  I'll update.